# Can't use group by, ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to count the number of rooms per hotel for all hotels. I have 3 tables, one with Hotel ID and hotel information, other with states where the hotels are (shares Hotel_ID) and a third one that have room info per Hotel ID. But I can get the "COUNT" and "GROUP BY" work in this sentence. I'm using Oracle SQLDeveloper

```
SELECT UPPER(A.HOTEL_NAME) "HOTEL NAME",
       B.STATE AS STATE,
       COUNT(C.ROOM_NUMBER)

FROM HOTEL A 
     INNER JOIN STATE B ON B.ID_STATE = A.ID_STATE  
     INNER JOIN ROOM C ON C.ID_HOTEL = A.ID_HOTEL  

GROUP BY A.ID_HOTEL
ORDER BY A.HOTEL_NAME ASC;
```

When I try it without the "COUNT" and "GROUP BY" clauses it shows without problem the hotel name in the first column and in the 2nd the state where the hotel is it.

Anyone knows why I can't get the number of rooms per hotel (in a 3rd column) grouped by hotel IDs?

```
SAMPLE DATA:
HOTEL TABLE                   ROOM TABLE                STATE TABLE
==========================    =======================   ======================
ID_HOTEL  | HOTEL_NAME        ID_HOTEL  | ROOM_NUMBER   ID_HOTEL  | STATE
40        |STARDUST HOTEL     40        |101            40        |CALIFORNIA
50        |GREENTREE HOTEL    50        |101            50        |ARIZONA
```

I'm expecting something like this:

```
RESULTING VIEW:
HOTEL_NAME     |STATE       |ROOM_COUNT
STARDUST HOTEL |CALIFORNIA  |1
GREENTREE HOTEL|ARIZONA     |1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing columns in your `GROUP BY` expression.  Haven't got an SQL environment handy so I'm not able to run this (plus you didn't provide a sample data set so not sure if cardinality etc. is correct), but try:

```
SELECT
    UPPER(A.HOTEL_NAME) "HOTEL NAME",
    B.STATE AS STATE,
    COUNT(C.ROOM_NUMBER)
FROM HOTEL A 
INNER JOIN STATE B ON B.ID_STATE = A.ID_STATE  
INNER JOIN ROOM C ON C.ID_HOTEL = A.ID_HOTEL  
GROUP BY A.ID_HOTEL, A.HOTEL_NAME, B.STATE
ORDER BY A.HOTEL_NAME ASC;
```

Notice I've added the two non-aggregate columns from your `SELECT` clause into your `GROUP BY`.

**Edit**

Check out [This SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00df2/1/0) - let me know if I've misunderstood your scheme etc.  It's working for me with minor modifications.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I see and now understand why you added the two non aggregate columns, however, I'm still getting the same error :(. Give me a sec to upload some sample data!

Comment: No worries!  Check out the fiddle in my edit and let me know if it works for you or if I've misunderstood something about your question.